# Submit data from an iOS4 app to an ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ios4

I have an iOS4 app I am developing and data is stored in a SQLite database.

I would like the ability to submit local data from the app to a global SQL Server database on an ASP.NET website.

My initial thought was to create a web service on the ASP.NET site that is consumed by the app. My experience developing web services is limited so I was wondering if this is a sound idea, what obstacles there are, or if there might be a better approach.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Services work great.  We use SOAP and return XML, but you could use JSON, you'd just need a JSON Serializer.  Check out http://json.codeplex.com/ for that.  Web Services are nice, because they abstract a lot of the business logic that may be necessary to get / send data to the SQL Database.  Also, they prevent direct access to your SQL Server.

Comment: Ditto, my iOS to DB server experience has been web services as well. Works great.